# Open textfile and read line by line

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have this code which i need to convert from vb6 to vb.net but i can't get my head around it.

```
 Open textFile For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1) 
        Line Input #1, textline
        If Left(textline, 5) = "56,1," Then
            kraj = 1
            If Left(Right(textline, 4), 1) = "+" Then
                Open textFile2 For Output As #2 
                Print #2, "53,1,______,_,__;"
                 Print #2, "56,1,______,_,__;"
             Close #2
                Close #1
                Exit Sub
            Else
                a = InStr(textline, ";")
                cilj = Right(textline, Len(textline) - a)
                a1 = InStr(cilj, ",")
                cilj1 = Right(cilj, Len(cilj) - a1)
                a2 = InStr(cilj1, ",")
                If bfr <> 0 Then
                    cilj2 = Right(cilj1, Len(cilj1) - a2)
                    broj = Left(cilj2, Len(cilj2) - 1)
                Else
                    broj = Left(cilj1, a2)
                End If
                If IsNumeric(broj) = True Then
                    broj = CDbl(broj)
                    Close #1
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    MsgBox "Error", vbCritical, "Error"
               Close #1
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop
```

How would I convert it to VB.NET, do i use same approach or i need to put lines in array. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Reader object and them with that object you can read line by line.
Example:

```
Dim reader = File.OpenText(filetoimport.Text)

    Dim line As String = Nothing

    While (reader.Peek() <> -1)
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        // Your code
    End While
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, taht helped. But i'm still not sure how would i read/parse those lines, specifically this part of code: 

    `If Left(textline, 5) = "56,1," Then
            kraj = 1
            If Left(Right(textline, 4), 1) = "+" Then
                Open textFile2 For Output As #2 
                Print #2, "53,1,______,_,__;"
                 Print #2, "56,1,______,_,__;"
             Close #2
                Close #1
                Exit Sub
            Else`

Comment: If you need to read line by line, i think that with my code is enough and you can ommit it maybe.